# Windows 10 - Set Login wallpapers as 1440p

Tags: windows-10

Every time when I wake up my PC, I need to pass the PIN code. As you all may know, by default, Windows 10 presents random wallpapers each time. I've got no problem with this kind of feature, but the thing is, it presents 1080p wallpapers (or lower), and my monitors are 1440p.

I was wondering if there's a way I can tell Windows 10 to show 1440 wallpapers, so the photos won't look blurry-ish.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the resolution of Windows spotlight images, but you can use images of your choice.

In Settings > Personalization > Lock screen select Picture or Slideshow, instead of Windows spotlight.

[image: Lock screen options]